# Android: Linking Edit Text field to button

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, switch-statement

I am creating a times tables app, in which one of the activities allows the user to enter which times tables they would like to view, then the app will bring up that times tables.(e.g. 6x5=30) etc.

Below is the xml layout I have created for the activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:padding="15dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvTop"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="I want to see the: "
            android:textSize="25dp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etEnterNumber"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Enter Number..."
             >
        </EditText>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvBottom"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Times tables!"
            android:textSize="25dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnGo"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:text="Go" 
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>r

    </LinearLayout>
```

And this it the java class I have created thus far for the classes functionalitiy:

```
public class ViewTimesTables extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

        // Declaring Vars
        Button go;
        EditText enterNumber;
        TextView top;
        TextView bottom;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // setting equal to text layout View
            setContentView(R.layout.view);

            // calling method to intialise vars
            initialiseVars();

        }// on create end

        /**
         * method to initialise all of the buttons, textviews etc used to clean up
         * the onCreate.
         */
        private void initialiseVars() {
            // Setting up (initialising) all the buttons text views etc from the xml
            // (vid 25)
            go = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnGo);
            enterNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etEnterNumber);
            top = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTop);
            bottom = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvBottom);

        }

        /**
         * Method with on click listener that adds functionality for all of the
         * buttons, text views etc
         * 
         * @param v
         */
        public void onClick(View view) {

            // switch statement which determines what is clicked
            switch ((view).getId()) {
            case R.id.etEnterNumber:

                // code to read user number (i.e. between 1 and 12)
                //And possibly link to go button
                break;

            case R.id.btnGo:

                // code to bring up new activity/screen with times table
                // of the number that was entered in edit text

                break;

            }

        }

    }
```

I am unsure how to add the correct functionality (probably within switch statement) so that when e.g. "6" is entered in the edit text box and the "go" button is pressed then the 6 times tables will be brought up in a new activity?

Comment: For Pete's sake some reviewers ***REALLY*** need to get a clue before knee-jerking to rubber-stamp any suggested edit that isn't outright vandalism! That suggested edit consisted entirely of changes that were useless (gratuitously bolding some text) and changes that were just plainly and obviously WRONG, while improving absolutely nothing. Timetables and times tables are not the same thing, and the question is clearly about times tables; and putting a parenthetical in a code span is an indisputably incorrect and unhelpful use of code spans. Unbelievable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would begin by looking at [Intents](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) to start a new activity and pass data to it.

A relevant tutorial is this [Android Intents Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidIntent/article.html)

Getting the text from a edit text is a simple as `enterNumber.getText().getString()`

You could then use a conditional statement to call the designated class.

Something like this would allow you to pass two values to the SixTimesTables class with the values 5 and 6 passed in.

```
if(enterNumber.getText().getString().equals("6")){
  Intent i = new Intent(this, SixTimesTables.class);
  i.putExtra("Value1", 5);
  i.putExtra("Value2", 6);
  // set the request code to any code you like,
  // you can identify the callback via this code
  startActivityForResult(i, REQUEST_CODE);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, How would i make the button open a new activity though depending on what is entered in edit text box?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want a dynamic layout for next activity.

It may help you.
http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/130521-android-part-iii-dynamic-layouts/

Then you can switch between activities as AndyGable mentioned.

Hopefully it'll help you.

Answer (score 0):

You really dont need the onClick for the editText you can handle if data is entered in the editText or not from the button click only like this:

```
public void onClick(View view) {

        // switch statement which determines what is clicked
        switch ((view).getId()) {
        case R.id.btnGo:

            // code to bring up new activity/screen with times table
            // of the number that was entered in edit text

            // check if editText has values or not
            if(TextUtils.isEmpty(mEditText.getText().toString())) {
                  mEditText.setError("Please enter a number");
             }else {
                  int number = Integer.parseInt(mEditText.getText().toString());
                  Intent intent = new Intent(YourCurrentActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
                  intent.putExtra("value", number);
                  startActivity(intent);

                  // it is always good to check if the value entered is a number only or not
                  // add inputType tag in the xml 
                  // android:inputType="number" for the editText.
             }

            break;

        }

    }
```

Now, in order to get value in the next activity do this:

```
// write this inside the onCreate of the Activity.
int  number;
if(getIntent().getExtras() != null) {
      number = getIntent().getIntExtra("value");
}

// use the number then to display the tables
```